# Sorting in SQL with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I'm practicing SQL a little bit, and I ran up to a ''problem''. The question is:

Create a list of students who are in their first year of school. Include the first name, last name, student ID number, and parking place number. Sort the results alphabetically by student last name and then by first name. If more than one student has the same last name, sort each first name in Z to A order. All other results should be in alphabetical order (A to Z).

```
SELECT student_id, first_name, last_name, parking_place_no
FROM students
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

That's perfectly clear to me, but the second part says that IF there are more students with same last name, I should put first name in descending order. Can anyone help? :)

Comment: _"All other results should be in alphabetical order"_ that was just a way to confuse you. Actually all other results ignore the first name because it's not relevant if the last name is different.

Comment: yeah, I got it now, I thought that they are giving me multiple conditions which was very suspicious to me :)
thanks :)

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below and let me know if its acceptable to your problem I have tested it and founds working perfect.

Comment: The question must mention that it has boundaries what SQL commands must not be in the answer. Please explain clearly at the beginning of the question.

Comment: I've just copy pasted here the whole task, and I wasn't sure whether they are asking something very simple, or less simple like you wrote :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re just being asked to sort by last name in ascending order (default) and first name in descending order:

```
SELECT student_id, first_name, last_name, parking_place_no
FROM students
ORDER BY last_name, first_name DESC;
```

Comment: oh yeah, I thought they are asking multiple conditions, not just ASC last name and DESC first name :D, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY last_name asc, first_name desc
```

`asc` is the default order if you don't provide one for a column.